# Problem with importing my own pacakge from pypi and testpypi

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I'm trying to publish a package I made on PyPI and i'm testing it on TestPyPI.I was able to upload the package and install it via pip but when I import it, it doesn't work as I would like.
The folder structure is:

```
package_name
|-- README.md
|-- setup.py
|
|-- package_name
    |--__init__.py
    |--__main__.py
    |--name.py
    |--tools.py
```

with a setup.py like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
  name = 'package_name',
  packages = ['package_name'],
  version = '0.1.0',
  ...
)
```

When i write `import package_name` i obtain the directory containing the setup.py and the package directory. To use this package i need to write `import package_name.package_name` that load the init file but it's verbose . How can i obtain the same results with `import pacakge_name` alone?
I tried to use `package_dir` but without results. In addition this iusse emerge only when i upload it on TestPyPI or PyPi but not when i use the development mode `pip install -e package_name`

Some additional information:

the init file contain `__version__ = '0.1.0'`

if i load package_name and i inspect it i obtain `<module 'package_name' (namespace)>`

Using find_packages doesn't resolve the iusse

Comment: This might not exactly answer your question, but if you can probably set up a sample project using [cookiecutter-pypackage](https://github.com/audreyfeldroy/cookiecutter-pypackage) to see how the package and `setup.py` is structured

Comment: or you can check out my fork that I added [here](https://github.com/rnag/cookiecutter-pypackage)